# Typescript types as a warning during the build

Tags: typescript, compilation

Is there any way how to not end build during the type error in typescript?

Sometimes I would like to print types errors like a warrning during the compilation.

it is possible?

```
src/scripts/example2.ts:20:11 - error TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

20           test = test.parentElement
```

This error will fail build, I would like to print just a warning

Answer (score 0):

You can supress the errors on a per line basis with `// @ts-ignore` or you can add

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": false
  }
}
```

to your tsconfig.json